# Silverlight 5 XAP does not add dependent Silverlight project dll

Tags: silverlight

I'm using Silverlight 5 RC and am facing a very perplexing problem. My project structure is like this..

1. The Actual Silverlight Application (references 1 and 3)
2. A "Common" Silverlight class project (references 3)
3. A "resources" and "constants" Silverlight project
4. An ASP .NET project hosted in IIS

Here's the problem...the resulting .XAP doesn't contain the .dll for project 3. The .dll is present in the bin directory of projects 1 & 2. The odd part is that at compile time, projects 1 & 2 can correctly load resources, classes etc from project 3 but not at run-time since the .dll for project 3 is missing from the XAP.

Any idea of what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Does your reference to project 3, in the main SL app, have it marked as `Copy Local = true`? That copy attribute drives the inclusion in the Xap, regardless of 2 referencing 3.

Comment: Yes, checked for that. Projects 2 & 3 have the same attributes in the project settings for Project 1. No differences noted.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I have same issue

Comment: No, I never found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this while having a similar problem - turns out assemblies with names ending in "Resources" won't be added to the XAP. Simply rename the assembly.

Edit: I stumbled across this blog, which gave me this answer: http://isolatedstorage.wordpress.com/2010/10/25/reserved-xap-file-names-resource-dll/

Comment: Hi adamsp, I no longer have access to the code. If any one else can test and verify this, please let me know. I can mark this as an answer. -Thanks!